MLE() Function in R -> Error in if (!all(lower <= start & start <= upper)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
I was trying to solve a maximum likelihood problem, but I just can't seem to get the mle() function to work. It always complains that optim() is returning non-finite values, somehow. I tried limiting theta to >0, so as to avoid computing log(0) and the natural logarithm of negative values, but to no avail. The mentioned error occurs. Does anyone have any info on why this might be happening?

library(stats4)


neg_loglik <- function(theta, x) {
  n <- length(x)
  a <- 4
  loglik <- n * log(theta) + n * theta * log(a) - (theta + 1) * sum(log(x))
  return(-loglik)
}

x <- c(4.37, 4.3, 5.15, 5.11, 5.15, 4.66, 6.15, 5.72, 5.87, 5.64, 4.05)

fit <- mle(minuslogl = neg_loglik, start = list(theta = 3.6), data = list(x=x), lower = c(theta = .Machine$double.xmin), upper = Inf, log = FALSE)
summary(fit)
theta_hat <- coef(fit)



q_hat <- qgamma(0.75, shape = theta_hat, scale = 1/4)


q_real <- qgamma(0.75, shape = 3.6, scale = 1/4)


desvio <- abs(q_hat - q_real) *100


resultado <- round(desvio, 4)


I tried altering the neg_loglik function too, and replaced it with the likelihood function, before applying the natural logarithm to it. Since, without ln() applied to it, the likelihood function should not compute Inf, -Inf or NaNs, for negative values of theta or theta = 0, since there is no instance of log(theta) in it, I expected optim to not return non-finite values, but it still did.
Error generated before the 1st one referred:
"Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) :
non-finite value supplied by optim"


Error in if (!all(lower <= start & start <= upper)) { :
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed


This error is avoided by supplying an initial value for parameter x of neg_loglik, e. g.
fit <- mle(minuslogl = neg_loglik, start = list(theta = 3.6, x = 5), …

Thanks for the feedback! I have just one question: by providing an initial x value, will the rest of the vector be ignored? Or can I just take the first element of the vector, supply it as initial value of x, and then supply the rest of the vector, without the first element?

If by the vector you mean what you pass as data, Ben Bolker already mentioned that mle doesn't actually take a data= argument.

@Armali's answer is technically correct, but I think you might have more luck switching to bbmle::mle2() (which is a modified version of stats4::mle(). Unlike stats4::mle(), bbmle::mle2() does actually take a data= argument ...
library(bbmle)
neg_loglik <- function(theta, x) {
  n <- length(x)
  a <- 4
  loglik <- n * log(theta) + n * theta * log(a) - (theta + 1) * sum(log(x))
  cat(theta, loglik, "\n")
  return(-loglik)
}
x <- c(4.37, 4.3, 5.15, 5.11, 5.15, 4.66, 6.15, 5.72, 5.87, 5.64, 4.05)
fit <- mle2(minuslogl = neg_loglik,
           start = list(theta = 3.6),
           data = list(x=x),
           lower = c(theta = .Machine$double.xmin),
           upper = Inf,
           method = "L-BFGS-B")


the cat() statement in the NLL function isn't necessary, but is convenient for debugging
if you want to use lower/upper bounds you have to use method = "L-BFGS-B"


Thanks a lot for the answer, but this is for a University project, and I am obliged to use the mle() function, and not mle2(). Should I face this challenge again, I will be sure to follow your recommendations.
